# sh and grep numbers only

Tags: shell, solaris, quoting, special-characters

I'm facing a problem and trying to find a solution that works in **sh**.
If I could use bash this code would work:

```
ls /a|grep ^[0-9]
```

Unfortunately this is not the case with sh, and yes I need to use sh. :)
Running in sh i get

```
ls /a |grep ^[0-9]
[0-9]: not found
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

If I remove the ^ the code works but I need only the files that start with numbers and not the ones that contains numbers.
Example, I need the files that are like:

```
12.00.2
2.222.1234.12
```

from the grep man page I should be able to use `^`.

For the time being my implementation was done by using:

```
ls /a|grep -v [a-z]|grep -v [A-Z]
```

As this will remove all the files that contains chars, but still if a file is .123.33 it will show up.

Comment: Can you use egrep instead of grep?

Comment: tip: `grep -v [a-z]|grep -v [A-Z]` == `grep -v "[a-z]\|[A-Z]"`

Comment: it wouldn't work well, I tried with egrep and no luck, but the solution provided by slm works like a charm :)

Comment: @rush, that syntax is not portable and will not work in the OP's Solaris. `grep -v '[a-zA-Z]'` or `grep -ve '[a-z]' -e '[A-Z]'` or `grep -vE '[a-z]|[A-Z]'` are standard though (though the behaviour is locale dependant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
ls /a | egrep "^[0-9]"
```

Per @Anthons feedback `egrep` is deprecated, so you can use `-E` as a switch to the normal `grep` command instead:

```
ls /a | grep -E "^[0-9]"
```

Per @Stephane's feedback the *extended* regular expressions (ERE's) aren't even necessary in this situation. Really what matters is the quoting of the `^[0-9]` to protect it from being interpreted by whatever version of `/bin/sh` you're using that's having the issue. So something like this would be the simplest fix to your issue:

```
ls /a | grep "^[0-9]"
```

-or-

```
ls /a | grep '^[0-9]'
```

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated (according to the man page), should recommend the use of `grep -E`

Comment: so I guess that bash interprets the ^ while when using sh it is up to grep, correct? and thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, `bash` is interpreting those instead of `grep`. I was surprised that you could pass those arguments bare like that w/o double quotes. I've only ever double quoted them to `grep`. You could've also put single quotes around them too.

Comment: You don't need extended REs here. That syntax works as well with BREs as with EREs so the `e` or `-E` are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

By `sh`, I think you're refering to the Bourne shell which was the shell of most Unix systems before the mid 90s and was `/bin/sh` on Solaris prior to Solaris 11.

On Solaris 10 and older, don't use `/bin/sh`. That shell is from another era. Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` instead.

In the Bourne shell `^` is an alias for `|` for compatibility with its predecessor the Thompson shell. So your command is like:

```
ls /a|grep |[0-9]
```

And the Bourne shell reports that it can't find a command called `[0-9]` and `grep` complains about not getting any argument.

Even if using a standard `sh` as opposed to the Bourne shell, I would recommend that you quote `^`. For instance `^` is a globbing operator in `zsh` when the extendedglob option is enabled.

In any case, if not `^`, you have to quote `[0-9]` since those are globbing operators. `[0-9]` would be expanded by the shell to the list of files in the current directory whose name is a single digit.

So:

```
ls /a | grep '^[0-9]'
```

Incidentally, in the Bourne shell

```
ls /a ^ grep '^[0-9]'
```

would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `ls` and `grep` for this; you can use a simple [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) `/a/[0-9]*`:

```
echo /a/[0-9]*
ls /a/[0-9]*
grep foo /a/[0-9]*
```

If you're using this in a script, beware that [parsing `ls` output is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with l0b0 grep is a bad idea here but anyway, here is an explanation of the issue and a workaround. On Solaris 10 and older, `/bin/sh` is an antiquated shell that shouldn't be used for anything but running legacy scripts. You really should use `ksh`, `bash` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` instead.

The root cause here is `^` used to be the original way to specify a pipe in the early Unix times. Solaris `/bin/sh` inherited this archaelogical feature.

The workaround is then quite simple, just escape the caret one of these ways:

```
ls /a |grep \^[0-9]
```

or

```
ls /a |grep "^[0-9]"
```

or

```
ls /a |grep '^[0-9]'
```

Comment: The first one would fail if there were a `^0` and `^1` file in the current directory though. You beat me by 7 seconds on the issue's Bourne source ;)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Why would the first one fail ? I just checked and it worked just fine.

Comment: Because the shell would expand it to `ls /a | grep '^0' '^1'`. That is, it would search for lines starting with `0` in `^1` and ignore the output of `ls`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Got it, I overlook the "and". Thanks.